# How does the damage of the Unkempt Harold (legendary Torgue pistol) work?

Tags: borderlands-2

I recently got a 'Hard Unkempt Harold', a legendary Torgue pistol which fires multiple bullets per shot:

[image]

How does its damage work? Is the damage indicated in the 'Damage' stat, split per bullet fired per shot, or is every bullet doing 100% of the damage indicated in the damage stat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It deals the listed damage per projectile. Also, like all Torgue pistols, each projectile deals an additional 100% splash damage (which cannot crit).

Comment: Thanks to this info, this weapon will be put to good use by my Gunzerker.